# Launching an exe file with passing an argument through Python

Tags: python, command-line, exe

I need to write a script that will run my exe file and pass an argument to it via the Windows command line.

I created an exe file with the code

```
with open(input(), 'r') as file:
    y = file.read()

while True:
    print(y)
```

I've tried different ways to pass the argument, but nothing comes out. Here is an example of one of my options

```
import subprocess


exe = 'C:\\Users\\barha\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject7\\exe.exe'
text = 'C:\\Users\\barha\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject7\\text.txt'

subprocess.call([exe, text])
```

Thanks

Comment: `input` is for taking arguments from stdin, not from the arguments of a program. If this is the intended behaviour, you should do a `subprocess.call([exe], stdin=text)`

Comment: @DecowVR, Thanks! Fixed 'input' to 'fileinput.input()', I messed up a little more and everything worked out)